# GetFunctionPointerForDelegate and pin pointer

Tags: delegates, c++-cli, interop, function-pointers, unmanaged

Hi this is in regard to some code given in C++ CLI i action which i have trouble understanding.The code is given below

```
        delegate bool EnumWindowsDelegateProc(
            IntPtr hwnd,IntPtr lParam);   
        ref class WindowEnumerator
        {
        private:
            EnumWindowsDelegateProc^ _WindowFound;   
        public:
            WindowEnumerator(EnumWindowsDelegateProc^ handler) 
            {
                _WindowFound = handler; 
            }
            void Init()
            {
                pin_ptr<EnumWindowsDelegateProc^> tmp =  &_WindowFound;
                EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)                   
                    Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(
                    _WindowFound).ToPointer(), 0);        
            }
        };
```

In the above code _WindowFound has been pinned so GC wont moove it.The Question is

1. Isn't tmp  only valid inside Int() thus _WindowFound pinned only
   during call to Int() ?
2. If thats the case Isn't there a chance the delegate location in
   memory might change at the time EnumWindows calls it as a function
   pointer?

Answer (score 2):

A pin_ptr<> automatically unpins, RAII-style, when code execution leaves the block that it is declared it.  So it will be pinned for the entire body of the Init() method in your code.  So your 2 bullet does not apply.

It is notable that the code is in not infact correct.  It works, but by accident.  Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() invokes the stub compiler to auto-generate the native code that's needed to allow the native code to invoke the delegate target.  The lifetime of that stub is controlled by the lifetime of the delegate object.  In other words, as soon as the delegate object gets garbage collected, the stub will be destroyed as well.

Pinning the delegate object does *not* in any way affect the stub.  It is already unmovable, the GC never moves code.  It works by accident because pinning an object requires creating an extra GC handle for the object (GCHandle::Alloc), enough to prevent premature collection.

It doesn't make an enormous difference in this kind of code, EnumWindows() is slow anyway.  Not necessarily the case when you call other native code that requires a callback, avoiding pinning should always be a goal in general.  All you have to do is let the jitter see a reference to the delegate object beyond the code where it can still be used, like this:

```
void Init() {
    EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)
                Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(
                _WindowFound).ToPointer(), 0);
    GC::KeepAlive(_WindowFound);
}
```

Very efficient, GC::KeepAlive() doesn't generate any code, it just tells the jitter to extend the lifetime of the _WIndowFound reference so it can't be collected while EnumWindows() is executing.  Even that is overkill in this specific case since *somebody* is going to have a reference to the WindowEnumerator object in order to retrieve _WindowFound, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: So if i understand correctly the delegate object is free to be moved in memory but the stub some how make the necessary mapping?